# Read one line at a time using shell

Tags: sql, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script. It will read one line at a time, assign the values to macros, then run a query with macros. After query is done, it will read the second line, create macros, run queries...
I developed the code below, but it will read all lines together then run the query. Should I use do i=1 to n ?

```
#!/bin/sh
$HOME/.profile
file=$1

OutputTable=$2

file=rule_flg.txt

cat $file|(
        read flg table_num rule_num

        while test "$flg" != ""
        do
           echo table_num is $table_num and rule_num is $rule_num 
           echo time is `date`

           (here are some parameters of database)... -v flg=$flg -v table_num=$table_num -v rule_num=$rule_num -f query_1.sql &> query_1.log

           read flg table_num rule_num
        done
        )

    echo run finished!
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of what you describe, what about reading the file line by line with the `while read; do ... done < file` syntax?

This way, every iteration will just contain the data from the current line.

```
while IFS= read -r flg table_num rule_num
    echo "table_num is $table_num and rule_num is $rule_num"
    echo "time is `date`"

    (here are some parameters of database)... -v flg=$flg -v table_num=$table_num -v rule_num=$rule_num -f query_1.sql &> query_1.log

done < "$file"
```

You can find more details by reading [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Note also that it is good to quote whatever variable you are working with, to prevent problems on formatting, etc. So say `echo "$var"` instead of `echo $var` unless you are very sure you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

So your question seems to be - "the script I wrote will read all the lines together then run the query, but I want it to execute the query once for each line it reads"

Since your script isn't complete or testable, I can't really debug it. :)

It is, however, a bit overly complex.  Since you dont need to get variables or other shell data out side of the subshell, you can just do a `cat $file | while read vars; do echo $vars;done` type of thing.

the `while read` will read each line of input into a variable (or set of variables), and execute the inner part of the loop once for each line.

A hacked up version of your script to show it:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=rule_flg.txt
echo "1 2 3" > $file
echo "3 4 5" >> $file
echo "4 5 6" >> $file


cat $file | while         read flg table_num rule_num
 do
           echo table_num is $table_num and rule_num is $rule_num
           #do your other things here
done
```

produces

```
%% sh whileread.sh
table_num is 2 and rule_num is 3
table_num is 4 and rule_num is 5
table_num is 5 and rule_num is 6
```

Now, there are many other ways to approach this - and there's no handling for the case where you send more than 3 arguments to read (they'll get stuffed into `$rule_num`...) but assuming your input data is consistently whitespace/tab delimited into 3 columns it should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I would take another approach here. As `awk` is part of POSIX, I dare to ignore your requirement of shell.

General pattern:

```
awk 'prog' inputfile | sh
```

So you write the repetitive statements with `awk`. When you are satisfied with the result, you pipe it to sh.

If you'd like some specifics, please post a sample of your input data and the commands that you want to execute in the end.